# Using the same FacetWP's facet twice

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, facet, facetwp

we are using WordPress FacetWP plugin for dynamic filtering the content on our site. We however have one a bit specific requirement we can't achieve. We need to embed one facet twice on the same page and "sync" selected values in it.

The reason is we have two types of visual. The sample is here:
https://oseva.webees.dev/osivo/kukurice-oseva-hybrids/

Both three images on top and "Kategorie" part below should be the same facet and they should sync values once you select an item in any of them. For now just the second facet works like that, not the first one with the images.

Do you place have an idea how to solve this? I tried to work with two facets and sync their values and many other things and any of it worked.

Thanks, Jakub

Comment: Facing the same issue: One Facet is displayed in the sidebar (only for desktop devices). The same Facet appears again inside the content area (only for mobile devices). My problem is, that FacetWP always uses the mobile facet values, regardless of what I enter in the sidebar...

Comment: Did you already figure out how to solve it? I have the same issue.